# How can i check if a number is present within another number if i am storing the number as an integer data type?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, linear-algebra

I want check if integers contain a particular number within them i.e. **say we have the numbers 134, 340, 3450, how can we check if the numbers contain 34 in them**. The case is trivial if we store the numbers as string however is it possible to do so while we store them as an array integers?

My initial thought is that we may have to use the Modulo operator with multiples of 10!

Comment: Which is it: C or C++? You should have at least started writing something, so you should include that too.

Comment: Something like .... `int foo(int number) { while (number > 10) { if (34 == (number % 100)) return 1; number /= 10; } return 0; }`

Comment: Please remove the `linear-algebra` that—this has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 2):

Your initial thought was headed in the right direction. The first step is to count the digits in the number to be located. The number "34" has two digits, so the module is 10 to the 2nd power, or 100. If the number had only one digit, the module is 10. If the number has three digits, the module is 1000. And so on.

Then, this becomes a matter of:

1. Start with the integer to be searched.
2. Take the remainder of the integer divided by the modulo.
3. If it is equal to the number you're searching for, you're done.
4. Otherwise divide the integer by 10, and go back to step 2, but stop when the integer value reaches 0 (not found).

How to compute the original modulo is going to be your homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `snprintf` to convert your `int`s to strings, then `strstr` to check if present. Something along this line:

```
char buffer[20] = "";
int n = 3450;
snprintf( buffer, 20, "%d", n );
printf( "%s\n", strstr( buffer, "34" ) ? "present" : "not present" );
```

Comment: That is actually a good use of the *ternary* operator. It optimizes well and is flexible enough to use almost anywhere. Few recognize how many different conditional situations can be solved by the simple *ternary* (now when you start nesting them, readability tanks....)

Comment: The question states that "stor[ing] the numbers as string" is to be avoided. This qualifies as storing numbers as a string. Even though they are stored temporarily, they are still stored.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a purely binary solution (no conversion to string). *NOTE: unsigned values only.*

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<unsigned long> nums = { 3450, 1233, 3, 34, 3534, 10003400, 0 };
    const unsigned long pattern = 34;

    unsigned long mod = 10;  //power of 10 that will isolate the pattern number of digits
    while ((pattern % mod) != pattern) mod *= 10;

    //test all of the numbers in the vector
    for (const auto& num : nums) {
        auto test = num; //copy so we can mutate it.

        for (; (test % mod) != pattern && test > mod; test /= 10);
        if ((test % mod) == pattern) 
            std::cout << num << " contains " << pattern << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

displays:

```
3450 contains 34
34 contains 34
3534 contains 34
10003400 contains 34
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to convert your integer to a string. Here is an example. Note this method requires C++11 so make sure you set up your compiler correctly.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    int num1 = 134;
    int num2 = 320;


    string temp = to_string(num1);
    if (temp.find("34") != -1){
        cout << "34 is in this integer!\n";
    }
    else {
       cout << "34 isn't in this integer.\n";
    }

    temp = to_string(num2);
    if (temp.find("34") != -1){
       cout << "34 is in this integer!\n";
    }
    else {
       cout << "34 isn't in this integer.\n";
    }

      return 0;
    }
```

Outputs: 
34 is in this integer!
34 isn't in this integer.

Answer (score 0):

Another non-string version:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number1;
    int number2;

    printf("input number1: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);

    printf("input number2: ");
    scanf("%d", &number2);

    int divisor = pow(10, (int)(log10(number1)) + 1);
    printf("divisor: %d\n", divisor);

    while (number2) {
        if ((number2 - number1) % divisor == 0) {
            printf("Yes\n");
            return 0;
        }
        number2 /= 10;
    }

    printf("No\n");

    return 0;
}
```

build with `gcc test.c -o test -lm`, and test:

```sh
test git:(master) ✗ ./test
input number1: 34
input number2: 1343403450
Yes

test git:(master) ✗ ./test
input number1: 35
input number2: 1343403450
No
(next_stock) ➜  test git:(master) ✗
```